# filter by year or month from mysql datetime cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

I have a table in a database in a CakePHP application that has a `date` field. The datatype of that field is DATETIME. So it shows like this in the table:

```
2013-08-10 13:34:45
```

I would like to add a condition in a find() query to filter by year or by month. To filter by year, I can use the LIKE condition to do something like:

```
$condition = array(
    'MyModel.date LIKE' => '%2013%'
);
```

But how can I filter by months? the approach above will not work because I can have for example something like this as a date:

```
2013-12-11 11:11:11
```

If I do LIKE '%11%', my results will be wrong because the month of the previous date is actually November (or december if you live in Canada). So, how can I add a condition on the date field of my table to filter by the correct month?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHERE MONTH(date)=6    // June
```

You can also use the `YEAR` function

```
WHERE YEAR(date) =2013
```

**[Referene](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)**